# How can developers view issues in mantis 2.5.1

Tags: mantis

I am new to mantis,I am using mantis 2.5.1 windows application installer,how can I make developers see reported issues from their workstation each developer will have his own pc and want to check his assigned defects,please help and thank you in advance

Comment: Did you install mantis on your machine? It's supposed to be on a server.

Comment: yes I have installed it on my local machine,but if i installed it on a separate server how could me and others connect to it,should each use the mantis installer and install mantis on his machine or what?

Comment: or I should install xammp on the server machine and install the mantis windows application installer on each machine and connect to the xammp configuration servers.

Answer (score 0):

Put Mantis on a server, make accounts and give them to your developers. For more help setting up Mantis, read the [Documentation](https://www.mantisbt.org/docs/master/en-US/Admin_Guide/Admin_Guide.pdf).